# Can I use Sencha with this Ext JS 1.0? How to upgrade from Ext JS 1.0 to the latest version?

Tags: extjs, upgrade, sencha-cmd

I want to upgrade the enterprise application that was developed in Ext JS 1.0  to the latest version? does anyone know any idea about the process? it seems that some of the methods/properties have been changed, in that case, do I have to rewrite the whole system?

Comment: It's not only that everything changed, but also the way to write an application. ExtJS started to use the MVC pattern, then fully MVC and now to MVVM. Nowadays code should look completely different. You have to do a full rewrite and learn about MVVM (data-binding, viewModel, viewController, scss in folder with view, workspace). Even the documentation changed... For starters it might be a good idea to get help on that task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you would to rewrite it, when this is `1.0` vs. `7.5`.
When creating a new project and then adding the legacy code, at least the config files would work - but likely nothing would work. The problem with partial rewrites is that commonly there's clutter left, rewriting from scratch and migrating class by class leaves the least clutter. That's alike comparing Windows `1.01` to `11`; when the current version wasn't written in an IDE, the code quality may also be low. `sencha-cmd` will in best case update the config files, in case it can even read them, but it won't update JS classes.